# Paypal sandbox to live account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Moving from sandbox to live 
I have Password, Username and Signature and my sandbox implementation working fine.
but when i change it to live i did not find any Password, Username and Signature here I have Client ID, Secret and Paypal account.
Am I missing something here?
Are they same ?

```
Password => Client ID;
Username =>  Paypal account;
Signature => Secret;
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same, Client/Secret is for the new REST APIs.

To obtain your live Username/Password/Signature for older Classic APIs, go to http://www.paypal.com/api -> Classic NVP/SOAP Credentials

And of course, when using live credentials, remove "sandbox." from the domain of all endpoints you are connecting/redirecting to.